# Declaring variables in docker-compose

Tags: variables, docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, version

I want to let my application know which image version it is running on.

The idea was to pass the Docker image tag into the image as an environment variable. However I don't want to change the version number in both the image line AND in the ENV variable line all the time.

Example:

```
version: "3"

VERSION=0.2.3

services:
  app:
    image: myimage:$VERSION
    environment:        
       - APPLICATION_VERSION:$VERSION
```

Is it possible to declare variables in order to update all values together or is there any other solution available?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot define `$VERSION` inside the `docker-compose.yml`.

You have two options for this:

- define it in a `.env` file
- send as a command line argument when you run the `docker-compose` command. e.g. `VERSION=0.2.3 docker-compose up -d`